# Build Android App with Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, node.js, apk

I'm trying to build my `html5` with `node.js` to mobile application (Android APK). It is like a chat box for those who are connected on the same wireless network. But my problem is this, when I'm coding my app on my desktop, I'm using the node.js software to run the codes. How will I do it then in building my mobile App (Android APK)?

If that's not possible, what do you recommend?

Comment: Are you serving `HTML` files from `nodejs` ?

Comment: I have my html5 files on the client folder...

Comment: Yes sir. i am serving it in node.js

Comment: You will need a server which can serve your files..

Comment: is it possible that i can make a local server mobile?

Comment: Yes you can... Access your app using same WIFI and access it using `Local-IP` instead of `localhost:port`...

Comment: since it's an application you don't want to serve files with a server, otherwise the user won't have anything to use if he is offline. Just use the server as an API and put the html and all files needed in the app itself

Comment: You may want to look at Cordova http://cordova.apache.org

Comment: cordova? Can i build an app there with node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js can only act as a server ( back-end ) of your app . You could use your HTML file and convert it to an apk with a compiler , but it's not worth the trouble. If you run your node server on a localhost you can access it with your phones browser with " your ip:port" . But again, your computer must always be running node , or deploy it to a cloud service like heroku to use it anywhere.